# Netbeans: Incorrect credentials for repository

Tags: git, ssh, netbeans

I am trying to clone a repository from github to Netbeans. However, I get the error written above.
If I run

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

It says I am successfully authenticated.
And if I run

```
ssh-add -l -E sha256
```

I get

```
256 SHA256:THECODEHERE myemail@gmail.com (ED25519)
```

It looks like my SSH are configured right, so I do not know exactly what is happening. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first that Netbeans is using an SSH URL (`git@github.com:<user>/<repo>`)

[image: https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/74/ide/git/github-repo-small.png]

If your key has a default name, you don't have to enter its path/passphrase, but if the error persists, that can be a test to make: specify epxlicitly the private key and its passphrase.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. However,  Netbeans is in fact using an SSH user, and I tried both with leaving the Private Key File in blank and uploading my Private key file, but still it did not work.

Comment: I meant URL, not user, sorry. I have fixed that typo in the answer.

Comment: I got what you mean and yes, I just copied the one from GitHub....

Comment: @sailorcoding What version of Netbeans are you running? Witch which version of Git and version of the OS (Linux, Windows, Mac?)

Comment: I am using Kali Linux 2020 64-bit, and both the Git and Netbeans are updated to the latest version

Comment: @sailorcoding Is Netbeans running with the same account as your current Linux account, or is there anything executed with `sudo` (ie. as root)?